# Como ler um arquivo com uma lista de emails?

Tags: php, email

Tenho um arquivo de texto com muitos e-mails e quero guardar tudo num banco de dados, como faço para pegar cada e-mail do arquivo em PHP?

Os e-mails estão separados por virgula.

Comment: Exisstem apenas emails nesta lista?

Comment: Sim, só tem emails

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) para ler os *e-mails* e colocá-los em uma `array`.

```
$texto = file('emails.txt');
```

Agora basta utilizar o [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) para capturar os *emails* e separá-los pela vírgula.

```
$emails = explode(",", $texto);
```

Comment: Só como leitura complementar: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 2):

Partindo do pré-suposto que o banco tenha a tabela emails, e que o arquivo seja `teste.txt`:

```
// Pega o conteudo do arquivo teste.txt
$arquivo_texto = file_get_contents('teste.txt');

// Cria um array com os emails do arquivo teste.txt
$emails = explode(',', $arquivo_texto);

// Abre uma conexão com o banco de dados mysql
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nome_do_banco", "root", "");

// Loop para inserção no banco de dados
foreach ($emails as $value) {
 $rs = $con->query("INSERT INTO emails VALUES ?");
 $rs->bindParam(1, $value);
 $rs->execute();
}
```